# KVO: not receiving notifications on NSTableView's -selectedRowIndexes?

Tags: macos, cocoa, selection, nstableview, key-value-observing

I'm trying to have a custom subclass of NSTableView observe the value of its own `-selectedRowIndexes` property, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to receive the notifications properly. My subclass looks like this (using ARC):

```
@implementation MyTableView

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
        [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selectedRowIndexes" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selectedRowIndexes"];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    NSLog(@"change: %@", change);
}

@end
```

However, I never see `-observeValueForKeyPath:...` get called. Am I missing something?

I'm also open to a better solution - the reason I want to do KVO rather than relying on the delegate's `-tableViewSelectionDidChange:` method is that I'd like both the previous and current values for `selectedRowIndexes`, rather than just being able to get the current selection. If there's a way to do that without KVO on this property, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not seeing KVO notifications, I would open a radar at bugreport.apple.com. The reason is likely that they're not fully KVO compliant. I haven't tested, but I wouldn't be shocked.

As to how to do this without KVO, that's fairly straightforward. Use <strike>`tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:`</strike> `tableView:shouldSelectRow:`. Check the current value, and the value to be added. Return `YES`.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the `-tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` docs? I'm not seeing it on either NSTableView or NSTableViewDelegate.

Comment: Sorry; that's embarrassing. I didn't check if this was Mac or iOS. Fixed.

Comment: I think that gets me part of the way there - is there an equivalent I can use to look at deselection? I'd like to perform an action on both selection and deselection of a particular row. (Maybe `-tableView:selectionIndexesForProposedSelection:`?)

Comment: Not certain. You may have to subclass UITableView to get all of what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I found the solution :

Bind the NSTableView view Selection Indexes to the array controller, key selectionIndexes